# Bad number of arguments for type constructor in Isabelle/hol

Tags: record, isabelle, concrete, extensible

I am a newbie in Isabelle/hol and I have this record declaration:

`record ('v,'w) fca = object_set :: "'v set" attribute_set :: "'w set" inc_set :: "('v×'w) set"`

and I want to instantiate to obtain a concrete record like:

`definition Concrete_fca :: fca where "pt1 ≡ (| object_set ={''a'',''b'',''c''}, attribute_set = {1::nat,2,3},inc_set = {(''a'', 1),(''a'',3)} |)"`

But, I am getting an error: Bad number of arguments for type constructor: tuto2.fca

NB: tuto2 is the name of my theory and fca is the name of the record
Please can someone help me resolve this issue.
Thanks

I searched online for the same type of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your definition. First, `fca` is a type constructor, not a type, so you must apply it to some type arguments to get a type (this is what the error tells you). In your case this is `(string, nat)`.

The other problem is that you want to define `Concrete_fca` but then give an equation for `pt1`. Giving the same name in both places gives you something like this:

```
definition Concrete_fca :: "(string, nat) fca" where 
  "Concrete_fca ≡ (| object_set ={''a'',''b'',''c''}, attribute_set = {1::nat,2,3},inc_set = {(''a'', 1),(''a'',3)} |)"
```